# How to SELECT records and display text along with COUNT?

Tags: php, mysql, select

[I am using an example in this question, the real problem I have is very similar, but it would be too complicated to write it down here ;) ]

So, I have a database table:

```
  id   |   text
-------+------------
  1    |   Google 
  2    |   Yahoo
  3    |   Google
  4    |   Bing
  5    |   Yahoo
  6    |   Google
  7    |   Yahoo
  8    |   Google
```

I want to SELECT them all and then display them like this:

```
Google 4
Yahoo 3
Bing 1
```

So I want to order the phrases by the number of appearances in the database...
It might sound a bit complicated... But I think my problem can be understood with the example.

So what should I do? What is the appropriate code for this in PHP/MySQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select text, count(text) 
from your_table 
group by text
order by count(text) desc
```

Comment: Not an issue here, but note that this `count(text)` counts rows with non-null `text`, unlike `count(*)`.

Answer (score 6):

```
select text,count(*) AS cnt from there group by text order by cnt desc;
```

Like this?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT text, COUNT(id) AS ordering 
FROM table 
GROUP BY text 
ORDER BY ordering DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT text, COUNT(*) FROM your_table
GROUP BY text
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(id) as count, text from table group by text order by count desc
```

I did not try it but could be correct